# dict keys with spaces in Django templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates, whitespace

I am trying to present a dictionary from my view.py at the HTML template such as:

```
test = { 'works': True, 'this fails':False }
```

and in the template:

This works without a problem:

```
{{ test.works }}
```

But a dictionary key that is having an empty space between words such as 'this fails' doesn't work:

```
{{ test.this fails }}
```

I get this error:

> Could not parse the remainder: `' fails'` from `'this fails'`

How can I overcome this problem? I am not the one filling the models, so I can't change the keys of the dict to remove spaces.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The filter you want is something like

```
@register.filter(name='getkey')
def getkey(value, arg):
    return value[arg]
```

And used with

```
{{test|getkey:'this works'}}
```

source: http://www.bhphp.com/blog4.php/2009/08/17/django-templates-and-dictionaries

Comment: Don't forget to {% load myfilter %} in the template

Comment: @Ross - that linked website should come with a warning sign. Put on your sunglasses!

Comment: the filter needs to stay in a file inside a templatetags dir. more info @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474734/django-custom-template-filter-cant-work

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any standard solution in Django. I think it is possible with a template filter.

You may be interested by this article http://push.cx/2007/django-template-tag-for-dictionary-access (the author is using template tag term but in fact it is a template filter)

I hope it helps

Comment: That looks like it'd work, but for the record, that's not a template tag, it's a filter (looks like whoever wrote that article made that mistake too).

Comment: It's not a mistake. It predates the term "template filter" by several years.
(I am the author of the blog post.)

Answer (score -4):

That doesn't look right to me. Can you do the following?

```
{{ test['works'] }} 
{{ test['this fails'] }}
```

This is how dictionary access in python typically works.

Comment: Could not parse the remainder: '['works']' from 'test['works']'

Comment: Yep, you access dictionary values given a key using `.` notation in Django templates.

Comment: Looking at the documentation, I'm getting the feeling that they didn't want spaces to be used. I'm seeing stuff like person.first_name, but never anything else. You can try looking at the parser code in django.template.__init__ but it is very long and complicated.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275735/how-to-access-dictionary-element-in-django-template