# Django templates: value of dictionary key with a space in it

Tags: django, django-templates

In a Django template, is there a way to get a value from a key that has a space in it?
Eg, if I have a dict like:

```
{"Restaurant Name": Foo}
```

How can I reference that value in my template? Pseudo-syntax might be:

```
{{ entry['Restaurant Name'] }}
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906129/django-template-and-python-dictionary-data-structure-question

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is no clean way to do this with the built-in tags.  Trying to do something like:

```
{{ a.'Restaurant Name'}} or {{ a.Restaurant Name }}
```

will throw a parse error.

You could do a for loop through the dictionary (but it's ugly/inefficient):

```
{% for k, v in your_dict_passed_into_context %}
   {% ifequal k "Restaurant Name" %}
       {{ v }}
   {% endifequal %}
{% endfor %}
```

A custom tag would probably be cleaner:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def dictKeyLookup(the_dict, key):
   # Try to fetch from the dict, and if it's not found return an empty string.
   return the_dict.get(key, '')
```

and use it in the template like so:

```
{% dictKeyLookup your_dict_passed_into_context "Restaurant Name" %}
```

Or maybe try to restructure your dict to have "easier to work with" keys.

Comment: If you're dictionary is nested this works well: `result = the_dict;
  for key in keys:
    if hasattr(result, 'get'):
      result = result.get(key, '');
    else:
      break;
  return result`

Comment: Would you know how to combine this with the {% if %} tag in Django? I'm trying to do something like this {% if dictKeyLookup dict_name "key" %} do something {% else %} do something else

Answer (score 16):

You can use a custom filter as well.

```py
from django import template
register = template.Library()
    
@register.filter
def get(mapping, key):
    return mapping.get(key, '')
```

and within the template

```
{{ entry|get:"Restaurant Name" }}
```

Comment: Its works for me. Created an folder inside app called templatetag with two files __init__.py and get.py(which holds the above code). Also added {% load get %} in top of html template

Comment: Correction, the directory should be called 'templatetags'; note the 's' at the end. Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/