# Django HTML can't read the values of the dict

Tags: python, html, django, dictionary, render

When I pass a simple dict `(myDict = {"key": "value"})` throught render to html, it creates an error as the html can't read the values of the dict ..

`{{ myDict["key"] }} <!--- prompts an error-->`

`django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '['key']' from 'myDict['key']'`

*Why didn't I pass the value directly? Because my question is not about this particular example. I'm searching for a more effecient way to use in case I wanted to pass bigger dicts and avoid writing down a for loop and if conditions on every line.*

Comment: Django templates use dot notation even for dictionaries.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511405/how-to-get-key-value-in-django-template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this in the template:

```
{{ myDict.key }}
```

As django uses dot notations for dictionaries for templates.