# How do I iterate and index a list in Django template

Tags: django

```
<!-- we want the first to be visible -->
{% for j in listOfStoresUsed %}
    <div class="col-sm-8" style="display: none; margin-left: 6em;" id = "store-{{j}}">
        {% for i  in itemsOrganizedByStore  %} 
            <img  width="200em" height="200em" src={{i.item.imgURL}}> <p>{{i.item.name}} Q:{{i.quantity}}</p><br>

        {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

`itemsOrganizedByStore` is a list, and I want to do something like:

```
for i in itemsOrganizedByStore[x]
```

`x` being an index that would be declared in a for loop above. How can I use a number for x in Django?

Comment: Show your view for this template, how do you get `listOfStoresUsed` and `itemsOrganizedByStore`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you want get key and value in template

```
{% for key, value in your_dict.items %}

    {{ key }}-{{ value }}

{% endfor %}
```

Your question already at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511405/how-to-get-key-value-in-django-template).