# Accessing a dict element who's key begins with an @

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a dict passed to my template, some of the element names / keys begin with an @ symbol, ie: 
    { '@id': 123, '@name': 'Alex' }

Is there a good / clean way I can access these elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A custom template tag is the only way to access dictionary keys with special characters. The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970244/django-templates-value-of-dictionary-key-with-a-space-in-it) provides a good example.

For the lazy:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def dictKeyLookup(the_dict, key):
    # Try to fetch from the dict, and if it's not found return an empty string.
    return the_dict.get(key, '')
```

Which you would use like so:

```
{% dictKeyLookup your_dict "@blarg!#$^&*" %}
```

As homework, you could also convert this into a simple filter, which would give you a syntax like:

```
{{ your_dict|getkey:"@blarg!@#$%" }}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was expecting as much to be honest, but I'm so new to django I wasn't sure if it was just some syntax I'd missed. I've gone ahead and implemented as a filter, looks fairly neat still.

Oh and shouldn't it be `{{ dict|getkey:"name" }}` for the filter? And not `{% ... %}`.