# Django look up dictionary value in template and sort by date

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I am passing a dictionary to my template with this view - 
`views.py`

```
def personlist(request, id):
    data = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/app_name/cities/' + id + '/persons/').json()
    context = RequestContext(request, {
    'persons': data['results'],'count': data['count'],
})
    @register.filter(name='lookup')
    def cut(value, arg):
    return value[arg]
    {{ mydict|lookup:item.name }}

    return render_to_response('template.html', context)
```

where `test_set` is a dictionary inside `results`. I am using this view to render the template this way -

```
{% for person in persons %}
<a href="{% url 'person_detail' person.id %}"><p>{{person.name}}</p></a>
<p>{{person.test_set}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

But that just displays the entire dictionary value - `[{u'test_name': u'test', u'date': u'2015-12-15T20:57:51.556145Z'}]` while I just want the date. I tried using a custom template to try and use `person.test_set.date` but it's not working.

Also, given the names and the dates is there a way to create a lookup to display names that were added on a daily/weekly/monthly basis?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? errors? nothing showing?

Comment: @Sayse Sorry. I meant not showing anything.

Comment: The `person.test_set.date` should be the correct way as you can see in [this other question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2970244/1324033).. What custom template did you try? The one in your first snippet?

Comment: Yes the one in my first snippet

Comment: please format your code.

Comment: `{{ mydict|lookup:item.name }}` what exactly is this in `cut` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be calling your custom template in the wrong way.

```
@register.filter(name='lookup')
def cut(value, arg):
    return value.get(arg, '{} not found'.format(arg))

{{ person.test_set|lookup:'date' }}
```

I've also modified the return value to return a message at least if it doesn't manage to find the key.

---

Your comment just made me realise that test_set isn't a dictionary, its a *list* of dictionaries. I'd imagine you want to iterate over these first then get the dates

```
{% for test in test_set %}
     {{ test.date }}
     {# or {{ test|lookup:'date' }} #}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Getting an error `'list' object has no attribute 'get'`

Comment: @SaketMishra - Ah of course, I've updated my answer now

Comment: Also could you give me a hint as to how I should proceed for the second part of my question?

Comment: @SaketMishra - I'm not sure its pretty vague (perhaps make a new question but would need describing in more detail). I'd probably make a model in your database to store the test results correctly and then you can perform db filters etc