# set data in html django

Tags: html, json, django

I learning django rest. And now i wont output some json data in html. My json:

```
{'Resul': {'Period Start': '2017-01-01', 'Period End': '2017-12-12'}}
```

then i send it json to html:

```
 context = {'Resul': json_data['date']}
 content = render_to_string('balance.html', context)
```

**json_data['date']** - `{'Period Start': '2017-01-01', 'Period End': '2017-12-12'}`

in html i write this code

```
 Period: {{ Resul['Period Start'] }} - {{ Resul['Period End'] }}
```

but have error:

```
Could not parse the remainder: '['Period Start']' from 'Resul['Period Start']'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django templates: value of dictionary key with a space in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970244/django-templates-value-of-dictionary-key-with-a-space-in-it)

Comment: @iklinac no, not dublicat. I create it by myself

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend you not to use spaces in dictionary key names, change them for underscores and do it like this:

```
 Period: {{ Resul.Period_Start }} - {{ Resul.Period_End }}
```