# Django custom template filter can't work

Tags: django

I have an errror:
**'run_target' is not a valid tag library: Template library run_target not found, tried django.templatetags.run_target**

I don't know why it can't work, even i add 'db.templatefilters' it can't work too...
Can anyone help me? thank you :)

Below is my file structure:

```
db/
    models.py
    templatefilters/
        __init__.py
        run_target.py
templates/
    run.html
```

run_target.py

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def dictKeyLookup(the_dict, key):
       return the_dict[key]
```

run.html

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
**{% load run_target %}**
{% block content %}
<div style="margin-left:150px; margin-top:10px">
<a href="/home">Home</a> >> <b>run</b>
</div>
<form name="form" method="post">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Delete" style="margin-left:149px; width:80px; height:30px">
<table border="1"; style="margin-left:150px; border-collapse:collapse;margin-top:10px"; cellpadding="4" borderColor=black>

{% for run in run_list %}
    <tr>
    <td>{% dictKeyLookup target_dict run.id %}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First thing first: Did you **restart** your server after making the changes? It's trivial but most people get stuck because of this.

---

Is `db` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting?

If so, then it looks like the two other things you're missing are:

- an `__init__.py` file in your `db` folder itself (you've got one in your `templatefilters` directory, but not its parent directory)
- the `templatefilters` folder should be called `templatetags` (see the [Code layout](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout) section of the documentation).

Incidentally, `db` is not a very good name for an app - call it something that more closely identifies *what* it does.

Comment: thanks for you answer, i don't know the folder name 'templatetags' can't be changed, thanks again :)

Comment: and don't forget to restart the server... seems trivial, but that was my problem

Answer (score 0):

If everything is done as in the documentation:

- **init**.py inside app folder, and inside templatetags folder
- app name in the INSTALLED_APPS section from settings.py

Then the problem can be solved restarting the server, if you have coded the module with the new tags/filter during server was running.