# How to do a Django Template dictionary lookup when key has special characters?

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-templates

In the django documentation it says that . notation will do a lookup in the following order

```
#Dictionary lookup. Example: 
foo["bar"]
#Attribute lookup. Example: 
foo.bar
#List-index lookup. Example: 
foo[bar]
```

In my project I have a dictionary:

```
foo = {'ba-r':'...}
```

But using . notation causes an error, which appears to be because the entire 'foo.ba-r' is a variable as described in the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups).

```
foo.ba-r
```

Is there any way to properly access the 'ba-r' key of my dictionary?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use foo["ba-r"]?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I access dictionary keys that contain hyphens from within a Django template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252387/how-do-i-access-dictionary-keys-that-contain-hyphens-from-within-a-django-templa) and [dict keys with spaces in Django templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906129/dict-keys-with-spaces-in-django-templates)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you already discovered, you cannot access such a key in your template without raising a `ParseError`. You can use [a custom filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) for instance:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def get_key_value(some_dict, key):
   return some_dict.get(key, '')
```

And use it like

```
{{ entry | get_key_value:"ba-r" }}
```

Or change your dictionnary structure so it does not contain such keys!