# Use variable as dictionary key in Django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I'd like to use a variable as an key in a dictionary in a Django template. I can't for the life of me figure out how to do it. If I have a product with a name or ID field, and ratings dictionary with indices of the product IDs, I'd like to be able to say:

```
{% for product in product_list %}
     <h1>{{ ratings.product.id }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

In python this would be accomplished with a simple

```
ratings[product.id]
```

But I can't make it work in the templates. I've tried using with... no dice. Ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to access dictionary element in django template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275735/how-to-access-dictionary-element-in-django-template)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to prepare your data beforehand, in this case you should pass list of two-tuples to your template:

```
{% for product, rating in product_list %}
    <h1>{{ product.name }}</h1><p>{{ rating }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks cji! I was trying to avoid another object, but it doesn't really matter... it's all cached anyway.

Comment: You don't need to prep the data in the view, you can achieve the same thing by calling `items` on the dictionary that's already in the context -- `{% for product, rating in product_list.items %}` will work.

Answer (score 103):

Create a template tag like this (in yourproject/templatetags):

```
@register.filter
def keyvalue(dict, key):    
    return dict[key]
```

Usage:

```
{{dictionary|keyvalue:key_variable}}
```

Comment: You also need a bunch of peripheral stuff to make this work so make sure you check out the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: Can this be chained for nested dicts? Something like `{{dictionary|keyvalue:key_variable|keyvalue:another_key}}` ?

Comment: Theoretically yes, try it out ;)

Comment: This is such a trivial thing. Why doesn't django support this out of the box?

Comment: @mango because they want to stay away from `logic` in templates and encourage putting it in the view

Comment: Need to add more descriptions

Answer (score 16):

Building on eviltnan's answer, his filter will raise an exception if `key` isn't a key of `dict`.

Filters should never raise exceptions, but should [fail gracefully](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters). This is a more robust/complete answer:

```
@register.filter
def keyvalue(dict, key):    
    try:
        return dict[key]
    except KeyError:
        return ''
```

Basically, this would do the same as `dict.get(key, '')` in Python code, and could also be written that way if you don't want to include the try/except block, although it is more explicit.

Comment: instead of dict[key] you just use the built-in python dictionary get method. e.g.: return dict.get(key, '')

Comment: You should also catch a potential TypeError. Parameter "dict" is not guaranteed to be  a Python dict.

Answer (score 15):

There is a **very dirty** solution:

```
<div>We need d[{{ k }}]</div>

<div>So here it is:
{% for key, value in d.items %}
    {% if k == key %}
        {{ value }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```