# Django template variables as key for a list

Tags: django, templates, django-templates

I'm coming from this question [Use variable as dictionary key in Django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894365/use-variable-as-dictionary-key-in-django-template)

i've this context created in my view:

```
{'cats': {'LIST1': ['a','b','c'], 'LIST2': ['aa','bb','cc','dd'], 'LIST3': ['f','g']}}
```

what i want to do is to print the list title and then all the items, something like

```
LIST1:
- a
- b
- c
```

for all the lists, so i did this in my template

```
{% for  l_name, l in cats %}
    {{ l_name }}

    {%for lv in l %}
        {{ lv }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

and this prints **only** the list names, without printing out the list. where's the mistake?

thanks

Comment: use `{{ l[lv] }}` instead of `{{ lv }}` ?

Comment: mmm, i don't think i can use [] in templates. anyway i found the problem. i need to create touple with () not {}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to iterate over keys and values, you can use:

```
{% for name, lst in cats.iteritems %}
.... 
{% endfor %}
```

This just calls the `iteritems` method of a dictionary, which returns an iterator over a list of 2-tuples.

[Django's `{% for %}` tag documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#for) has some nice example of this too.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, the problem is how the data are created. so instead of

```
{'cats': {'LIST1': ['a','b','c'], 'LIST2': ['aa','bb','cc','dd'], 'LIST3': ['f','g']}}
```

i need a list of touple so:

```
{'cats': [('LIST1', ['a','b','c']), ('LIST2', ['aa','bb','cc','dd']), ('LIST3', ['f','g'])]}
```