# Django template unable to access a dictionary lookup variable. What mistake am I doing in code?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'm learning django from djangobook.com

As an exercise, I'm trying to print all `HttpRequest.META` dictionary in the form of a table using template.

**views.py** contains

```
# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

def http_headers(request):
    return render(request,'headers.html',{'headers':request.META})
```

**headers.html** <-- template

```
<html><body><table border="1">
{% for k in headers.keys %}
<tr><td> {{ k }} </td><td>{{ headers.k }}</td></tr>
{% endfor %}
</table></body></html>
```

**Output:**

```
<html><body><table border="1">

<tr><td> TMP </td><td></td></tr>

<tr><td> COMPUTERNAME </td><td></td></tr>

<tr><td> wsgi.multiprocess </td><td></td></tr>

<tr><td> RUN_MAIN </td><td></td></tr>

<tr><td> HTTP_COOKIE </td><td></td></tr>
...
...
```

**Problem:**
Why is it unable to access `{{headers.k}}`?

djangobook.com says:

> Dot lookups can be summarized like this: when the template system
>   encounters a dot in a variable name, it tries the following lookups,
>   in this order:
>
> ```
> Dictionary lookup (e.g., foo["bar"])
> Attribute lookup (e.g., foo.bar)
> Method call (e.g., foo.bar())
> List-index lookup (e.g., foo[2])
> ```

So, `headers.k` must first match the **dictionary lookup** since headers is a dictionary. Right?

What am I missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`headers` is a dictionary, you should iterate over it using `items` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for)):

```
{% for key, value in headers.items %}
    <tr><td> {{ key }} </td><td>{{ value }}</td></tr>
{% endfor %}
```

You mistake is in using `{{ headers.k }}`, which is basically `headers['k']` - `request.META` don't have `k` key - that's why you are seeing nothing.

Hope that helps.

Comment: doesn't it first evaluate the value of `k` first and then use it?

Comment: nope, replace `k` with `HTTP_COOKIE` and you'll see the value. `k` is interpred as a string in this case. Though, if you use `{{ k }}` - you'll see the value of loop variable `k`. That's somewhat confusing, I understand.

Comment: Also see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894365/use-variable-as-dictionary-key-in-django-template