# Django dict key in template

Tags: django, templates

How can I do this:

```
x = 'id_1'
d = {'id_1':1, 'id_2':2}
print d[x]
```

in django template, I've tried this:

```
{% for field in form %}
    <tr>
        <th><label for="{{ field.auto_id }}" >{{ field.label }} </label></th>
        <td>Some text from dict: {{context_dict.field.auto_id}} {{field}}</td>
     </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

in context_dict.field.auto_id, I need context_dict.[field.auto_id]

Do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use variable as dictionary key in Django template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894365/use-variable-as-dictionary-key-in-django-template)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a python package called `templatetags` in your app folder, then create a file called something like `custom_tags.py`, and in that file put:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter()
def lookup(the_dict, key):
    return the_dict.get(key, '')
```

so now you can lookup the value by something like:

```
{{ context_dict|lookup:key }}
```

Note: Make sure to load the template tags into your template via `{% load custom_tags %}` (place it at the top of the file, but under any `{% extends %}` tags.