# Accessing a two dimensional array in Django template

Tags: python, django

I am building a betting app where users can bet on different games. I want to show users' bets for different games in a table such as one as below:

```
game #   |   user 1   |   user 2   |   user 3

game 1  |   XXXX    |   XXXX    |   XXXX

game 2  |   XXXX    |   XXXX    |   XXXX

game 3  |   XXXX    |   XXXX    |   XXXX
```

...

here's my view

```
users = User.objects.all()
games = Game.objects.all()
bets = Bet.objects.all()

user_bets = [[] for i in range(len(games))]

for i, game in enumerate(games):
    game_bets = bets.filter(game=game)
    for usr in users:
        user_bet = game_bets.filter(user=usr)[0]
        user_bets[i].append(user_bet)

data = {'games', games, 'users', users, 'user_bets': user_bets}
return render(request, 'bets.html', data)
```

But I don't know how to fill in the table using the 2d array `user_bets`. Any suggestions? Or if I'm doing the whole thing wrong any best practice to pass such data to template in Django?

Cheers

Comment: An easy way to do this is with a custom filter as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10700142).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Passing Multi-dimensional arrays to templates in django is not straight forward. I've been working on this problem for a while, so I know your question is old, but for the betterment of django society, here's what I've finally worked out...

```
users = User.objects.all()
games = Game.objects.all()
bets = Bet.objects.all()

user_bets=[]
game_title=[]

for i, game in enumerate(games):
    game_titles = [game.title]
    game_bets = bets.filter(game=game)
    for usr in users:
        user_bet = game_bets.filter(user=usr)[0]
        user_bets[i][usr.id]=user_bet
data = {'game_titles', game_titles 'users', users, 'user_bets': user_bets}
return render(request, 'bets.html', data)
```

You then want to define two template filters, which for ease can live in your views.py

```
@register.filter
def index(List, i):
    return List[int(i)]

@register.filter
def entry_num_array(List):
    return range(len(List))
```

Then in your template

```
{% for bet in user_bets %}
{{ game_titles|index:forloop.counter0}}:
    {% for counter in entry|entry_num_array %}
        {{entry|index:counter}}|
    {% endfor %}
    <br>                
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

For those who are looking for accessing a standard 2D array, you can use a nested loop:

**views.py**

```
content={'f':[[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7]]}
return render(request,'index.html',content)
```

**index.html**

```
{% for array in f %}
{% for content in array %}
<h1>{{content}}</h1>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking for accessing a combination of Lists,Touples, etc. you can programm a nested loop as mentioned above by "The Guardener" and     builtins if tags:

```
some_list={
           1:{('a','Answer1'),('b','Answerb')},
           2:{'Something':'else'},
           3:{'Something':'else'}
          }
```

Template: index.html:

```
{% for nested_list in some_list %}
{% for list_element in nested_list %}
    {% if list_element.0 == 'a' %}
      some_list[nested_list[list_element[0]=='a']]]: {{ list_element.1 }} # Answer1 
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I couldn't test this example only parts of it.