# Dynamic var name with content of another var in template

Tags: django, django-templates

I try to generate a var name from another var value.
To be more specific I'm in a loop and I try to display all parameters of an object, based on the loop incrementation.
Example:
I have a list of objects categories.
I have an object diplayer which contain parameters cat_1, cat_2, cat_3 etc
I try to do something like this

```
{% for category in categories %}
   {{ displayer.cat_(category.id) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Of course my probleme is (category_id) I really don't know how to get value of category.id to use it in the param name of the object.

For information I can not use a dictionary in place of the object displayer.

An idea?

Thanks a lot

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29664945/8060120

Comment: What is displayer ? Why cant you iterate over it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of logic has to be done in Python beforehand. See [this similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894365/use-variable-as-dictionary-key-in-django-template).

If you really really want to do the logic in the template (not advised), you can use [custom template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/).

Comment: Thanks I used custom template tags and it works fine. But I'm not sure we can say I do logic in the template it's juste that the vars in the dict are named weirdly, I just read a dict in the template