# How to get value from key when sending a dictionary to jinja

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I send my dictionary - content - to a template which looks like this. Inside content is multiple dictionaries. One of them is named like_dict which looks like this : {1: 18} {2: 14} {3: 15} and another is named info which holds my user id. I use this code to sort it:

```
{% for x in info %}
{% if x.id in like_dict %}
<p> the value is: {{ like_dict.x.id }} </p>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Everything seems to be working, except the part within the paragraph tags. When I replace x.id with the number of my ID (like this: like_dict.1 ) it prints '18' just fine. When I leave it as I have it in the example (like_dict.x.id), it finds x.id in like_dict, but only prints 'the value is:' without stating the dictionary value. When I try to do this - like_dict[1] - I get an error for using brackets. Can anyone direct me towards how I would go about printing only the value when the key matches my ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use square brackets to access the value of a variable key of a dict:

```
<p> the value is: {{ like_dict[x.id] }} </p>
```

Comment: that's what I thought. But it gives me this syntax error: Could not parse the remainder: '[x.id]' from 'like_dict[x.id]'

Comment: I don't think you're using Jinja2 then. With the default Django template language it does not support using square brackets to access dict values. Reconfigure your Django to use Jinja2 instead.

Comment: Thank you. Anyway to do it in Django Template language?

Comment: You're welcome. Unfortunately I don't think there is a way to do it in Django Template language, which was why I had to suggest that you switch to Jinja2 as the rendering engine for your Django instead.

Comment: This wound up working :) Just for your own future reference!                          
{% for r, b in like_dict.items %}

{% if x.id == r %}
<div id="like"><p><img src="/static/images/likeicon.png" height="25px" width="25px"><span id = "counter">{{ b }}</span></p></div>

{% endif %}
{% endfor %}

Answer (score 0):

What I would try in your situation is storing x.id in a variable inside of the template using the "with" keyword.

```
  {% for x in info %}
    {% for k, v in x.items %}
      {% if k == 'id' %}
        {% if v in like_dict %}
          {% for key, value in like_dict.items %}
            {% if key == v %}
              <p>The value is: {{ value }}</p>
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
```

Warning: **This is a very dirty solution.**

Comment: That comes up blank, as well.

Comment: Okay so I changed my answer providing a very dirty solution. Perhaps a better solution would be using custom django template filters. Check this post for more information on that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894365/use-variable-as-dictionary-key-in-django-template

Comment: I fixed it by adding .items to the end of the dictionary in the for loop.  Much thx for the help, tho!: {% for r, b in like_dict.items %} {% if x.id == r %} <div id="like"><p><img src="/static/images/likeicon.png" height="25px" width="25px"><span id = "counter">{{ b }}</span></p></div> {% endif %} {% endfor %}

Comment: You are welcome. Nice to know that you got things working!