# how to request session value in template django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-class-based-views, django-sessions

i want to fetch a session  value directly in myy template i have fom by which i request session and after that i am viewing that session in another html

my views.py where session got created

```
class Product_detail(View):
    def get(self, request, item_id,):
        item = Item.objects.filter(id=item_id)
        category_list = Categories.objects.all()
        items = Item.objects.order_by('-update_at')
        return render (request, 'product_detail.html',{"items" : item, 'category_list': category_list, 'item': items })

    def post(self, request, item_id):
        item = request.POST.get('item')
        size = request.POST.get('Size')
        cart = request.session.get('cart')
        if cart:
            cart[item] = size
        else:
            cart = {}
            cart[item] = size
        request.session['cart'] = cart
        print(request.session['cart'])
        return redirect('products:detail', item_id=item_id)
```

my views.py in which i want ot render session

```
class Cart(View):
    def get (self, request): 
        cart = request.session.get('cart', None)
        if not cart:
            cart = {} # or however you define your empty cart
        request.session['cart'] = cart
        ids = (list(cart.keys()))
        ids = (list(request.session.get('cart').keys()))
        item = Item.get_items_by_id(ids)
        print(item)
        return render(request, 'cart.html', {'items': item })
```

my html code

```
 <tbody style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
                              {% for item in items %}
                              <tr>
                                <th scope="row">{{forloop.counter}}</th>
                                <td> <img src="{{item.first.url}}" alt="" height="100px"></td>
                                <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                                  {% for key, value in request.session.cart.items %}
                                      {% if value == value %}
                                        <td>{{ value }}</td> 
                                      {% endif %}
                                  {% endfor %}
                                <td>{{item.price|currency}}</td>
                                <td> <a href="#">Remove</a> </td>
                              </tr>
                              {% endfor %}
                            </tbody>
```

so my session list has two values in it one is id and other is its size so want to show user it selected size right now it show both the id and size but i want to render only user selected size

any idea how to achieve that

filter

```
@register.filter
def item_size(cart , item):
    return cart[item]
```

[image: it look like this]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use variable as dictionary key in Django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894365/use-variable-as-dictionary-key-in-django-template)

Comment: @bdbd i tried but didn't work it say invalid filter

Comment: Can you update the question with what you've tried

Comment: updated the question have look

Comment: It should be `{{ request.session.cart|item_size:item }}`

Comment: @throwing keyerror like this<Item: shirt>

Comment: Does `request.session.cart` have shirt in it?

Comment: ye the item have shirt in it

Comment: but i want to fetch the selected size of user there

Comment: item name shirt

Comment: i think you didn't get it i want to fetch size which is value in the session it save like this {'2': 'S'} where 2  is the id and S is the size selected by user from select field and i want to show only s there becuase that the user selected size for that shirt

Comment: @bdbd now i think you got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so for requesting the session value you can not directly render it you have to create filter or that an then render it so here in my case i want to render the product size which is also it's value so in my templatetag folder i created a filter

my filter for fetching values of session

```
@register.filter(name='cart_size')
def cart_size(item, cart):
    keys = cart.keys()
    for id in keys:
        if int(id) == item.id:
            return cart.get(id)
    return 'Regular';
```

and in my template for rendering

```
{{item|cart_size:request.session.cart}}
```

so what it does as mentioned in question item id is key and size its value and i assigned the size to its item so what filter does it is looking for keys in cart and as you know the key is id so i assign id is equal to item.id and then it return the size which assigned with id and then in template i call it like this because all the value in cart so i am requesting that too otherwise it will throw error

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
    <td>{{ request.session.cart|item_size:item.id }}</td> 
    <td>{{item.price|currency}}</td>
```

This will get the size (which is the value in the dict) by using `item`'s id. To ensure that the keys are used as integers, add:

```
item = int(request.POST.get('item'))
```

Comment: it mean i have to do this for every other size

Comment: i want to show only that thing size not all the sizes

Comment: which user picked added screenshot how it looked evething is fetched except the size

Comment: i want the size under the size

Comment: Ok now it's clear. You can just do: `{{ request.session.cart|item_size:item.id }}`

Comment: This will get the item from cart in the session using item's id as key, and will return the size

Comment: i think 2 is the item id

Comment: Try to add this `item = int(request.POST.get('item'))`. The id seems to be saved as a string but being used as integer. You will have to recreate the cart from scratch, so delete it and make a new one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235647/discussion-between-bdbd-and-shreyash).

Comment: Thank you bro for your try but i figured it out by myself

Comment: All good! Great that you are not stuck anymore