# Why do you have to call .items() when iterating over a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

Why do you have to call [`items()`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) to iterate over key, value pairs in a dictionary? ie.

```
dic = {'one': '1', 'two': '2'}
for k, v in dic.items():
    print(k, v)
```

Why isn't that the default behavior of iterating over a dictionary

```
for k, v in dic:
    print(k, v)
```

Answer (score 176, accepted):

For every python container C, the expectation is that

```
for item in C:
    assert item in C
```

will pass just fine -- wouldn't *you* find it astonishing if one sense of `in` (the loop clause) had a completely different meaning from the other (the presence check)?  I sure would!  It naturally works that way for lists, sets, tuples, ...

So, when `C` is a dictionary, if `in` were to yield key/value tuples in a `for` loop, then, by the principle of least astonishment, `in` would also have to take such a tuple as its left-hand operand in the containment check.

How useful would that be?  Pretty useless indeed, basically making `if (key, value) in C` a synonym for `if C.get(key) == value` -- which is a check I believe I may have performed, or wanted to perform, 100 times more rarely than what `if k in C` actually *means*, checking the presence of the key *only* and completely ignoring the value.

On the other hand, wanting to loop just on keys is quite common, e.g.:

```
for k in thedict:
    thedict[k] += 1
```

having the value as well would not help particularly:

```
for k, v in thedict.items():
    thedict[k] = v + 1
```

actually somewhat less clear and less concise.  (Note that `items` was the original spelling of the "proper" methods to use to get key/value pairs: unfortunately that was back in the days when such accessors returned whole lists, so to support "just iterating" an alternative spelling had to be introduced, and `iteritems`  it was -- in Python 3, where backwards compatibility constraints with previous Python versions were much weakened, it became `items` again).

Answer (score 10):

**My guess:** Using the full tuple would be more intuitive for looping, but perhaps less so for testing for membership using `in`.

```
if key in counts:
    counts[key] += 1
else:
    counts[key] = 1
```

That code wouldn't really work if you had to specify both key and value for `in`. I am having a hard time imagining use case where you'd check if both the key AND value are in the dictionary. It is far more natural to only test the keys.

```
# When would you ever write a condition like this?
if (key, value) in dict:
```

Now it's not necessary that the `in` operator and `for ... in` operate over the same items. Implementation-wise they are different operations (`__contains__` vs. `__iter__`). But that little inconsistency would be somewhat confusing and, well, inconsistent.

Comment: Given that for _every_ other type of builtin iterable that I can think of, `x in foo` only if `i` in `for i in foo` assumes the value of `x` at some point, I would say that it would be a very __huge__ inconsistency.