# Pythonic way to convert a dictionary to a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

This is more of a question about programming style. 
I scrap webpages for fields such as: "Temperature: 51 - 62", "Height: 1000-1500"...etc  The results are saved in a dictionary

```
{"temperature": "51-62", "height":"1000-1500" ...... }
```

All key and values are string type. Every key can map to one of many possible values. Now I want to convert this dictionary to numpy array/vector. I have the following concerns:

- Each key corresponds to one index position in the array.
- Each possible string value is mapped to one integer.
- For some dictionary, some keys are not available. For example, I also have a dictionary that has no "temperature" key, because that webpage doesn't contain such field.

I am wondering what is the most clear and efficient way of write such a conversion in Python. I am thinking of building another dictionary maps the key to the index number of the vector. And many other dictionaries that maps the values to integers.

Another problem I am having is I am not sure about the range of some keys. I want to dynamically keep track of the mapping between string values and integers. For example, I may find that key1 can map to a val1_8 in the future.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to iterate over values in dictionary Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10498132/how-to-iterate-over-values-in-dictionary-python)

Comment: @Anycorn, thanks for your prompt comment, My question is different from that post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try a pandas Series, it was built for this.

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series({'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3})
s.values # a numpy array
```

Comment: One of the problem is not all dictionary have the same set of keys, Can pandas handle this? thanks

Comment: Yes. You may also want to check out pandas DataFrame for even more fun.

Comment: Thanks, I installed it, truly powerful tool. I did pd.DataFrame( {dd["name"]: pd.Series( dd) for dd in dictlist}) , where dictlist is a list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> # a sequence of dictionaries in an interable called 'data'
>>> # assuming that not all dicts have the same keys
>>> pprint(data)
  [{'x': 7.0, 'y1': 2.773, 'y2': 4.5, 'y3': 2.0},
   {'x': 0.081, 'y1': 1.171, 'y2': 4.44, 'y3': 2.576},
   {'y1': 0.671, 'y3': 3.173},
   {'x': 0.242, 'y2': 3.978, 'y3': 3.791},
   {'x': 0.323, 'y1': 2.088, 'y2': 3.602, 'y3': 4.43}]

>>> # get the unique keys across entire dataset
>>> keys = [list(dx.keys()) for dx in data]

>>> # flatten and coerce to 'set'
>>> keys = {itm for inner_list in keys for itm in inner_list}

>>> # create a map (look-up table) from each key 
>>> # to a column in a NumPy array

>>> LuT = dict(enumerate(keys))
>>> LuT
  {'y2': 0, 'y3': 1, 'y1': 2, 'x': 3}

>>> idx = list(LuT.values())

>>> # pre-allocate NUmPy array (100 rows is arbitrary)
>>> # number of columns is len(LuT.keys())

>>> D = NP.empty((100, len(LuT.keys())))

>>> keys = list(LuT.keys())
>>> keys
  [0, 1, 2, 3]

>>> # now populate the array from the original data using LuT
>>> for i, row in enumerate(data):
        D[i,:] = [ row.get(LuT[k], 0) for k in keys ]

>> D[:5,:]
  array([[ 4.5  ,  2.   ,  2.773,  7.   ],
         [ 4.44 ,  2.576,  1.171,  0.081],
         [ 0.   ,  3.173,  0.671,  0.   ],
         [ 3.978,  3.791,  0.   ,  0.242],
         [ 3.602,  4.43 ,  2.088,  0.323]])
```

compare the last result (first 5 rows of D) with *data*, above

note that the ordering is preserved for each row (a single dictionary) with a less-than-complete set of keys--in other words, ***column 2* of D *always* corresponds to the values keyed to *y2,***, etc., even if the given row in data has no values stored for that key; eg, look at the third row in data, which has only two key/value pairs, in the third row of D, the first and last column are both *0*, these columns correspond to keys *x* and *y2*, which are in fact the two missing keys

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I find Pandas to be a natural solution for my current problems.