# Using .iteritems() to iterate over key, value in Python dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Note: I have [read this post and Alex Martelli's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744568/why-do-you-have-to-call-iteritems-when-iterating-over-a-dictionary-in-python), but I don't really/fully understand his answer. It's a bit beyond my current understanding. I would like help understanding it better.

I understand that when you try the following for loop:

```
for key, value in dict:
    print key
    print value
```

you get:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Although you can loop over a dictionary and just get the keys with the following:

```
for key in dict:
    print key
```

Can anyone provide a slightly less-advanced explanation for why you cannot iterate over a dictionary using key, value without using `.iteritems()` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The other answer explains it well. But here are some further illustrations for how it behaves, by showing cases where it actually works without error (so you can see something):

```
>>> d = {(1,2): 3, (4,5): 6}
>>> for k, v in d:
        print k, v

1 2
4 5
```

The loop goes through the keys `(1,2)` and `(4,5)` and since those "happen to be" tuples of size 2, they can be assigned to `k` and `v`.

Works with strings as well, as long as they have exactly two characters:

```
>>> d = {"AB":3, "CD":6}
>>> for k, v in d:
        print k, v

A B
C D
```

I assume in your case it was something like this?

```
>>> d = {"ABC":3, "CD":6}
>>> for k, v in d:
        print k, v

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#42>", line 1, in <module>
    for k, v in d:
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Here, the key "ABC" is a triple and thus Python complains about trying to unpack it into just two variables.

Comment: While this is correct, it's not actually **helpful** to the OP, given the context of the question.

Comment: I'm hoping it **is** helpful by illustrating the behaviour with some examples, particularly one that actually results in the received `ValueError`. I'm adding more to my answer for this...

Comment: @DougR. How is it now?

Comment: Much better.  Rated a +1.

Answer (score 8):

Python has a feature called iterable unpacking. When you do

```
a, b = thing
```

Python assumes `thing` is a tuple or list or something with 2 items, and it assigns the first and second items to `a` and `b`. This also works in a `for` loop:

```
for a, b in thing:
```

is equivalent to

```
for c in thing:
    a, b = c
```

except it doesn't create that `c` variable.

This means that if you do

```
for k, v in d:
```

Python can't look at the fact that you've said `k, v` instead of `k` and give you items instead of keys, because maybe the keys are 2-tuples. It has to iterate over the keys and try to unpack each key into the `k` and `v` variables.

Answer (score 0):

While using `for xx in XX`, you are actually using an iterator to iterates the XX, and XX must be iterable. You can use `iter` function to get an iterator, as

```
>>> d = dict(a=1,b=2)
>>> i = iter(d)
>>> i
<dictionary-keyiterator object at 0x6ffff8739f0>
```

and using `next` to access the elements.

```
>>> next(i)
'a'
```

So in every iteration of `for k in d`, `k` will be assigned to `next(i)`, and it's only the key without value. e.g., in the first round of iteration,

```
k = 'a'
```

While `.iteritems()` will return another iterator with can get a tuple of key-value combined. Let's check this

```
>>> i = d.iteritems()
>>> i
<dictionary-itemiterator object at 0x6ffff873998>
>>> next(i)
('a', 1)
```

See? In the first round of `for k, v in d.iteritems()`, we actually get this assignment

```
k, v = ('a', 1)
```

Thus, if you using `for k, v in d`, you will get

```
k, v = 'a'
```

That's an illegal assignment.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.7.6 it seems that you may want to check for subproperties of the dictionary with `dict.has_key(property_name)`.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3 you can use items() to get a list of tuple pairs from the dictionary. So you can iterate over this list:

```
for key, value in dict.items():
    print key
    print value
```

If you iterate over the dictionary (without `.items()`) you iterate only over the list of its keys (a list of single values). So you cannot assign these single values to two values in the `for` loop.