# Calling Dict Item in Template

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to call a specific dict item in a template, however having trouble doing this.

Basically I am using a dict to display all my categories/subcategories of my database.

The dict is in the following format:  {'categoryname1': [subcategory1, categoryname2], "categoryname2": [a, b, c]}

I'm trying to do: 
**categoryname1** 
- subcategory1
- categoryname2
--a 
--b
--c

Here's my code. The line I'm having trouble with is this part: `{% for subcatlevel2 in subcats.items.subcat.1 %}`. Basically I'm trying to figure out how to pull the values when I know a particular key.

```
{% for cat in subcats.items %}
    {{ cat.0}}
    {% for subcat in cat.1 %}
        {{ subcat }}
        {% for subcatlevel2 in subcats.items.subcat.1 %}
            { subcatlevel2 }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}`
```

Comment: In general if `mydict={'a': 5}` then you can access this way `{{ mydict.a }}`

Comment: Or something like this: {% for key, value in subcats.items %}

Comment: Ok first one is not working. I tried putting `{{ subcats.subcat }}` below the `{{ subcat }}` part. Any idea why?

Comment: @DiegoNavarro gave you all you need to know. If it's still going sideways, update your code so we can have a better idea what might be messed up still.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to access dictionary element in django template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275735/how-to-access-dictionary-element-in-django-template)