# How to achieve Django nested expression, or evalute expression inside expression {{ {{ expr }} }}?

Tags: google-app-engine, django-templates

In python i am passing below context in django template:

```
{'expr': 'next_expr', 'next_expr': 'value'}
```

In template, i am trying to print 'value':

```
{{ {{ expr }} }}
```

I know above expression wont work but i want to achieve something like this:

```
{{ {{ expr }} }} ---> {{ next_expr }} ---> 'value'
```

Is there any method in django inbuilt by which i get 'value'?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly and the Python object is passed as `tmp` variable:

```
tmp = {'expr': 'next_expr', 'next_expr': 'value'}
```

you could do that in Jinja2:

```
{{tmp[tmp['expr']]}}
```

In Django all I could [find](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1724201) is something like this, but I don't think that this is what you want

```
{% for k, v in tmp.items %} 
  {{k}} - {{v}} |
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I get TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '[tmp['expr']]' from 'tmp[tmp['expr']]'

when I wrote your exact expression in template.

Comment: @LoveSharma Hmm... works nicely in Jinja2.. It should be the same.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1724201/8418 :(

Comment: raising answer... but not exact answer which i am looking and may be its not possible in django. So i implemented custom tag and work fine.  Thanks for your effort. :)