# Django template and part of a dictionary of lists

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-templates

in Django I want to display some entries in a dictionary of lists.

My context is:

```
keys = ['coins', 'colors']
dict = {'colors':['red', 'blue'],
        'animals':['dog','cat','bird'],
        'coins':['penny','nickel','dime','quarter'] }
```

Template code:

```
<ul>{% for k in keys %}
    <li>{{ k }}, {{ dict.k|length }}: [{% for v in dict.k %} {{ v }}, {% endfor %}]
{% endfor %}</ul>
```

I want to see:

```
* coins,4: [penny, nickel, dime, quarter,]
* colors,2: [red, blue,]
```

But what I actually see is keys but no values:

```
* coins,0: []
* colors,0: []
```

Note: I also tried `dict.{{k}}` instead of `dict.k`, but as expected that just gave a parse error in template rendering.  I'll get rid of the trailing comma with `forloop.last` after getting the basic list working.

What is the secret sauce for displaying selected values from a dictionary of lists?

The question [django template and dictionary of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13561009/django-template-and-dictionary-of-lists) displays an entire dictionary, but my requirement is to display only a few entries from a potentially very large dictionary.

Comment: Essentially Django makes it unnecessarily painful to use `dict` in templates and access in any normal way. You are right that the `dict.k` lookup is not working because it is looking for a literal `k` attribute rather than the value of your template variable. For this use case I would recommend writing your own custom tag or filter to do the work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem (as you suspected) is that dict.k is evaluated to dict['k'] where 'k' is not a valid key in the dictionary. Try instead to iterate each item pair using `dict.items` and only display the results for the keys you're concerned with:

```
<ul>{% for k, v in dict.items %}
        {% if k in keys %}
            <li>
            {{ k }}, {{ v|length }}: [{% for val in v %} {{ val }},{% endfor %}]
           </li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Is it `items` or `iteritems`?

Comment: @ShangWang items, my bad.

Comment: Yes, thanks for confirming my fears.  I was hoping to avoid processing an entire dictionary just to display a few entries, but I guess Django templates aren't that pythonic.   Looks like I'll have to rewrite views.py to pass in a bunch of subset dicts to the template.

Comment: The alternative is to write a simple template filter to do the dynamic lookup: it's three lines of code, see an example in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8000091/104349)

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
    {% for k, v in dict.items %} # instead of iterating keys, iterate dict
        {% if k in keys %} # if key found in keys
            <li>
                {{ k }}, {{ v|length }}: [{% for val in v %} {{ val }},{% endfor %}]
            </li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```