# Access a dictionary element in the Django template with a variable

Tags: python, django

The situation is the following. We render a view.

`return render(request, 'test.html', {'db_object': db_object, 'dict': dict }`

In the template we would now like to access the dictionary with `db_object.key`. In python you would normally do `dict[db_object.key]`. In the template you could do `{{ dict.some_key }}` to access the value. But in the following situation you obviously can't do `{{ dict.db_object.key }}`

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Why are you passing `dict`? You have access to your context dictionary in the template and you just need to do `{{ db_object.key }}`..? Or am I missing the point?

Comment: Cant you use the `.items`syntax? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275735/how-to-access-dictionary-element-in-django-template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been covered before, and the best solution I've found is to [create a quick custom filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000022/django-template-how-to-lookup-a-dictionary-value-with-a-variable/8000091#8000091). In case that link goes dead, here's the code (which I did not write, but am providing as reference):

```
@register.filter 
def get_item(dictionary, key): return dictionary.get(key)
```

And in the template:

```
{{ dict|get_item:object.key }}
```

Of course, make sure to call load on your template tags so they're visible to the renderer.