# Cannot Get Django Template to Print Formatted JSON

Tags: python, json, django

I'm struggling with printing a formatted JSON response from Watson's NLU API. I'm using Python 2.7 and Django 1.11. My views.py looks like this:

```
def nlu_analysis(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        text2send = request.POST.get('text2send')
        natural_language_understanding = NLUV1(
            version='2017-02-27',
            username='####',
            password='####')

    response = natural_language_understanding.analyze(
        text=text2send,
        features=[features.Entities(), ... features.SemanticRoles()])

        parsedData = json.dumps(response, indent=2)
    return render(request, 'analysis.html', {'data': parsedData})
```

My analysis.html looks like this:

```
  <div class="container text-left">
      <p>{{ data }}</p>
  </div>
```

The result of all of this is the data, with JSON brackets being printed on one line like this:

*{ "semantic_roles": [ { "action": { "text": "are", "verb": { "text": "be", "tense": "present" }, "normalized": "be" }, "sentence": "Batman and Superman are fighting the bad guys", ... "keywords": [ { "relevance": 0.931284, "text": "bad guys" }, { "relevance": 0.790756, "text": "Superman" }, { "relevance": 0.752557, "text": "Batman" } ] }*

If I run this within a for loop

```
<div class="container text-left">
    {% for d in data %}
        <p>{{ d }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

it simply prints on character on each line

{

"

s

e

m

...

suggesting that {{ data }} is a string, nothing more.

Clearly I am fundamentally misunderstanding something. Either it is something with respect to how json.dumps (including 'indent=2') works or how to deal with it properly in my template. I suspect the later as the information being passed via 'data' clearly contains all of the JSON syntax. If I place the one line result above result in a JSON validator it reformats and validates perfectly.

Any help for a complete rookie out there? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you json dump the data before passing it to the template? Your for loop will work perfectly without it

Comment: Sure enough removing the json.dumps got me a lot closer, but it only gets me the top level of the JSON feed. How do I get to each level of the JSON feed? Thanks so much Aswin.

Comment: In the example above when I added the for loop it printed 'semantic_roles' and 'keywords' from the example above. Not the next level down. Thanks again.

Comment: For that you will just need to nest your for loops similarly how you would access them with normal python code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you even parsing your response. `json.dumps` converts the `dict` object to string. You can instead directly use it as `return render(request, 'analysis.html', {'data': response})`.

Comment: Thanks Nikhil. That works and the for loop in the html above does print the top level of the json data. Now I need to figure out how to interate through each section in the html to print each level.

Comment: You cannot iterate directly on data. Try using `data.semantic_roles`.

Comment: Accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the value for a key in the dict object, you just need to do like this (for your example data),

```
{{ response.semantic_roles }}
```

Here `semantic_roles` will be interpreted as a literal string and not using the value of the variable “semantics”, if one exists in the template context. And `response` is the name of the context variable.

Or, If you want to get value of each key in he dict object using a loop, you may need to create a custom filter for your template,

```
from django.template.defaulttags import register

@register.filter
def get_item(dictionary, key): 
    return dictionary.get(key)
```

And in your template,

```
{% for key in response %}
{{ response|get_item:key }}
{% endfor %}
```

Of course, make sure to call load on your template tags so they're visible to the renderer.

Here are some helpful links,

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups
- [Accessing dictionary by key in Django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19745091/accessing-dictionary-by-key-in-django-template),
- https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/3371
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25266672/access-a-dictionary-element-in-the-django-template-with-a-variable&grqid=f2CFq5XB&hl=en-IN

Comment: Fazil, thanks for the additional info and the links. Incredibly helpful.

Comment: Appreciate the support..!!