# Accessing JSON data in template in Django

Tags: json, django

I have a view that retrieves a JSON file like this:

```
json_lang = requests.get('path/to/file.json').json()
return render(request, "chat/chatroom.html", {'jsonLang': json.dumps(json_lang)})
```

Let's say the json file is structured somewhat like this:

```
{
    "en": {
        "action.send": "Send",
        "chat.joined": "joined the chatroom",
        "chat.left": "left the chatroom",
...
}
```

If I try to access one of those strings in a template like this `{{ jsonLang.en.chat.joined }}` I get an empty output.

Other methods, like trying to access it like this `jsonLang["en"]["chat.joined"]` result in an error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /chat/
Could not parse the remainder: '["en"]["chat.joined"]' from 'json_lang.["en"]["chat.joined"]'
```

What's the correct method to do this?

Comment: Try with `json_lang["en"]["chat.joined"]` instead

Comment: Tried that already, I made a typo in my post. That's what gives me the error

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, `'jsonLang': json.dumps(json_lang)` means that you pass a string to template. You should use `'jsonLang': json_lang` to pass it as a Python dictionary.

Secondly, as dictionary lookup in Django templates are [implemented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/templates/#variables) with dot notation, this breaks if the key itself contains a dot.

One solution is adding a quick template filter that allows to access dictionary items by keys with dots - [Access a dictionary element in the Django template with a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25266672/access-a-dictionary-element-in-the-django-template-with-a-variable)

Comment: I tried with a key that doesn't contain a dot: I still get an empty output

Comment: I have to note that if I use ```{{ jsonLang }}``` I do get an output: the whole json file. Trying to acces any key in that file results in empty output.