# Create dictionary from 2 lists, use in django template

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I have 2 lists:

```
year_month_day_list = ['2017-02-12', '2017-02-11', '2017-02-10', '2017-02-09']

filename_prefix_list = ['2017-02-12_11-45-59', '2017-02-12_11-35-05', '2017-02-10_11-00-52', '2017-02-11_10-59-23', '2017-02-09_09-12-09']
```

If I can grab all of the filenames that match their associated ymd:

```
def filter_files(file_list, filter_param):
    return [f for f in file_list
            if f.startswith(filter_param)]

for unique_day in year_month_day_list:
        files_for_day = sorted(filter_files(
            filename_prefix_list, unique_day), reverse=True)
```

How can I create a dictionary that uses the unique_day as the key and the associated filenames for that day as the values?

Output should be something like:

```
dict = {'2017-02-12': ['2017-02-12_11-45-59', '2017-02-12_11-35-05'], '2017-02-10': ['2017-02-10_11-00-52']}
```

Then, how can I use those in my template? Something like:

```
<div class="thumbnail-row" id="thumbnail_row">
    <div class="row-date">
        <span>{{ unique_day }}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="">
        <form action="{{ filename_prefix }}/video/" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="image" name="filename_prefix" value="{{ filename_prefix }}" src="{{ MEDIA_URL}}thumbnails/2017/02/{{ filename_prefix }}.jpg">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the list items by their dates. The date can be sliced from the *datetime* strings and used as the *grouping* key. You can drop `sorted` if the *datetime* strings are already clustered by dates:

```
from itertools import groupby
from pprint import pprint

filename_prefix_list = ['2017-02-12_11-45-59', '2017-02-12_11-35-05', '2017-02-10_11-00-52', '2017-02-11_10-59-23', '2017-02-09_09-12-09']

dct = {k: list(g) for k, g in groupby(sorted(filename_prefix_list), lambda x: x[:10])}
pprint(dct)
# {'2017-02-09': ['2017-02-09_09-12-09'],
#  '2017-02-10': ['2017-02-10_11-00-52'],
#  '2017-02-11': ['2017-02-11_10-59-23'],
#  '2017-02-12': ['2017-02-12_11-35-05', '2017-02-12_11-45-59']}
```

To use the dictionary in your template simply pass it to the current context via your view function, and get its key-value pairs by calling its `items` method using `{% for k, v in dct.items %}`.

More generally:

```
{% for k, v in dct.items %}
     {% for dt in v %}
     <!- your html -->
     {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It looks like this is working great. However, I want the results returned in descending order for both the key and list of values. Basically I want the most recent day, then its files with the most recent file first. Can you suggest how I can accomplish that? Sort() on dct removes the values.

Comment: Pass `reverse=True` to `sorted` and save the result into `collections.OrderedDict`

Comment: Which result am I saving into `collections.OrderedDict`? This is what I have now: `dct = {k: list(g) for k, g in groupby(
        sorted(sorted_filename_list, reverse=True), lambda x: x[:10])}`

Comment: This: `dct  = OrderedDict((k, list(g)) for k, g in groupby(sorted(sorted_filename_list, reverse=True), lambda x: x[:10]))`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

For converting the lists into the desired format `dict`, you may use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) as:

```
from collections import defaultdict

year_month_day_list = ['2017-02-12', '2017-02-11', '2017-02-10', '2017-02-09']
filename_prefix_list = ['2017-02-12_11-45-59', '2017-02-12_11-35-05', '2017-02-10_11-00-52', '2017-02-11_10-59-23', '2017-02-09_09-12-09']

my_dict = defaultdict(list)
for year_month_day in year_month_day_list:
    for filename_prefix in filename_prefix_list:
        if filename_prefix.startswith(year_month_day):
            my_dict[year_month_day].append(filename_prefix)
```

where value hold by `my_dict` will be:

```
{
    '2017-02-09': ['2017-02-09_09-12-09'], 
    '2017-02-10': ['2017-02-10_11-00-52'], 
    '2017-02-12': ['2017-02-12_11-45-59', '2017-02-12_11-35-05'],        
    '2017-02-11': ['2017-02-11_10-59-23']
}
```

For accessing `dict` objects in Django's template, you will have to do something like:

```
{% for key, values in my_dict.items %} 
    {{key}}
    {% for value in values %}
        {{value}}
    {% endfor %} 
{% endfor %}
```

For more details, refer: [How to access dictionary element in django template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275735/how-to-access-dictionary-element-in-django-template)

---

Note: Do not use `dict` as variable name since [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-dict) is an in-built type in Python.

Comment: I appreciate the advice on not using `dict` as a variable. Noob mistake :)