# How to display a dictionary list in django template? (Could not parse the remainder)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

I've got a function that is creating a list:

```
import feedparser
import ssl

def rss(self):
    if hasattr(ssl, '_create_unverified_context'):
        ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
    rss = 'https://news.google.com/news?q=fashion&output=rss'
    feed = feedparser.parse(rss)
    articles = []
    for entry in feed.entries:
        articles.append({
                    "summary"    : str(entry.summary),
                    "link" : str(entry.link),
                    "title"   : str(entry.title),
        })

    return articles
```

on the return of articles, I am then trying to display this in the view

My views.py code is:

```
def results(request):
    rss_feed = RSS()
    articles = rss_feed.rss()
    return render(request, 'app/index.html', articles)
```

and then my template code is:

```
<ul>
{% for article in articles %}
    <li>{{ article['title'] }}</li>
{% empty %}
    <li>Sorry, no athletes in this list.</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

but I keep getting an error that reads:

> TemplateSyntaxError at /app/results Could not parse the remainder:
>   '['title']' from 'article['title']'

I created a separate script and just print to console and it prints without issue. But doesn't show in Django.

I'm new to Python and Django. Not sure what I've missed.

Update:
Using `{{ article.title }}` returns an error `context must be a dict rather than list.`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275735/how-to-access-dictionary-element-in-django-template

Comment: You've missed reading the actual documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/templates/#variables

Comment: Although it's not clear why you're putting the articles into dicts anyway. Why not send the article objects themselves to the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were passing the wrong context to the return function as you passed in your list directly to render. You have to pass your article list as a member of the context dictionary like this:

```
return render(request, 'app/index.html', {"articles": articles})
```

After this you can address the title of article as

```
{{ article.title }}
```

in your template.

Comment: `article.title` returns `context must be a dict rather than list.` as an error

Comment: return render(request, 'app/index.html', {"articles": articles})

You were addressing the wrong object.

Comment: thanks, this fixed my issue. Please update your answer and I will accept.