# Django templates accessing dictionary from another dictionary key

Tags: python, django

Seems trivial, but I'm iterating a dictionary, accessing another dictionary from the `id` key of that dict. Example:

```
{% for choice in choices %}
  {{ percentages[choice.id] }}
{% endfor %}
```

As in:

```
for choice in choices:
  percentages[choice.id]
```

Though I get a Django error:

> Could not parse the remainder: **'[choice.id]'** from **'percentages[choice.id]'**

Which I thought may work. I tried researching and changing `[choice.id]` into `|get:choice.id` as a potential resolution, but that also gave me another unhelpful error.

Comment: I think this solution will solve your problem
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275735/how-to-access-dictionary-element-in-django-template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275735/how-to-access-dictionary-element-in-django-template)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to access dictionary element in django template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275735/how-to-access-dictionary-element-in-django-template)

Comment: @HERAwais I think this holds SO integrity. The core question is indeed accessing dictionaries, though my confusion came from the iterating aspect. Since this question comes from the Django tutorial, I think future people will come across it with the same questions. If not, that's fair enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot access dictionary indices from django template. You have to register a custom template tag like this.

```
@register.filter
def from_dict(d, k):
    return d[k]
```

And use it like this.

```
{% for choice in choices %}
  {{ percentages|from_dict:choice.id }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That's neat. Where does this code reside? Above my views?

Comment: You have to create a package named `templatetags` inside your app and put a file in it (like `extras.py`). Then load them in templates like this `{% load extras %}`. Please see more on this [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/)