# Dictionary items not showing up in template in django

Tags: python, django

I have gathered data from two tables that is Orders and Purchases (joined) and saved that in dictionary, when I'm printing the qty on the console its giving me the value but when I'm trying to print the values on template it not showing up however columns from the orders table like first name last name status address is shown on the template but qty and product from the purchases table is not showing up on the template but can be easily printed on console
can somebody help???
Models.py

```
    Dispatcher = models.ForeignKey(Dispatchers , null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL )
   
    Firstname = models.CharField(max_length=200 , null=True)
    Lastname = models.CharField(max_length=200 , null=True)
    Email = models.CharField(max_length=200 , null=True)
    Address = models.CharField(max_length=200 , null=True)
    Country = models.CharField(max_length=200 , null=True)
    State = models.CharField(max_length=200 , null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200 , null=True)
    def __str__(self):
     return self.Lastname

class purchases(models.Model):
    orders_id = models.ForeignKey(Orders , null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL )
    product =  models.CharField(max_length=200 , null=True)
    qty =  models.CharField(max_length=200 , null=True)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=200 , null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
     return self.product
```

views.py file

```
    dispatcherOrders = {}
    orders = request.user.dispatchers.orders_set.all()
    
    for order in orders:
        dispatcherOrders[order] = purchases.objects.get(orders_id = order.id)
        print(dispatcherOrders[order].qty)
    
    return render(request , 'dispatcherOrders.html',{'dispatcherOrders' : dispatcherOrders})
```

dispatcherOrders.html

```
        {%for Orders in dispatcherOrders%}
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>{{Orders.Firstname}}</td>
        <td>{{Orders.Lastname}}</td>
        <td>{{Orders.Address}}</td>
        <td>{{Orders.product}}</td>
        <td>{{Orders.qty}}</td>
        <td>{{Orders.status}}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
```

Comment: At the end of the for loop try to print `dispatcherOrders` and include the data. It will be helpful to debug the issue

Comment: @Sabil  this is the result of print(dispatchOrders) {<Orders: Santos>: <purchases: Speakers>, <Orders: Richmond>: <purchases: Speakers>} and print print(dispatcherOrders[order].qty) is 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `dispatcherOrders` dictionary keys are orders and dictionary values are `purchases`:

```py
dispatcherOrders[order] = purchases.objects.get(orders_id = order.id)
```

yet you are iterating only on dictionary keys, the orders:

```
{%for Orders in dispatcherOrders%}
```

To get the info from purchases, iterate the dictionary items too.

So your template code should be similar to

```
        {%for Orders, Purchase in dispatcherOrders.items %}
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>{{Orders.Firstname}}</td>
        <td>{{Orders.Lastname}}</td>
        <td>{{Orders.Address}}</td>
        <td>{{Purchase.product}}</td>
        <td>{{Purchase.qty}}</td>
        <td>{{Purchase.status}}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
```

Here's how `.items` work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6285769/3694363