# How to go through a Django dictionary in HTML template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Im new to Django and I don't really have a clear idea how the Django Template language works but I have a dictionary that is something like this:

```
{
  "info":{
     "a":"test1",
     "b":"test2",
  }

}
```

How can I get the values for "a" and "b" in Django template.
I'm not sure if that makes sense but what I mean would look something like this in Python:

```
for i in info:
  print(info.i)
```

I already tried this but it didn't work

```
{%for i in info %}
   {% if info.i %}
      console.log('{{info.i}}')
   {% endif %}
{% endear %}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275735/how-to-access-a-dictionary-element-in-a-django-template

Comment: If you want a and b specifically, use `info.a` and `info.b`