# Django. "dictionary changed size during iteration" while not changing anything

Tags: django, django-templates

I think I am going insane here.
I am trying to iterate over a dictionary containing lists.

This is my code: (Yes, I know this is not enough to accomplish what I am trying to do, but I have shaved the code down to the minimum while still causing the problem):

```
{% for wc in response %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ response.wc }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

But i get this error `"dictionary changed size during iteration"`.

As anybody with half a brain can see, I am very much not changing ANYTHING in the dict of lists.

I am thinking of a hacky solution, just pass another list of of the keys to the template, which I can use to iterate over the list, like: `{%for key in keys%} response.key`.
This just seems like the wrong way to do it.

Comment: What is response? What do you pass to the rendering engine?

Comment: Why are you trying to access 'response.wc'? Go straigth for 'wc'

Comment: wc is the key, so wc would just print the string. response.wc prints the value of wc.

Comment: response in a dict with lists in them. I am sending response inside context to the render.

Comment: Please provide a [mre], "_I have shaved the code down to the minimum while still causing the problem_" this isn't enough at all to cause the problem. We should be able to copy paste your code and run it on our side to reproduce the problem. In your case you should atleast share enough code of your view that renders this template so that we would understand what `response` is.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you cycle through a variable. You should do:

```
{% for wc in response %}
 {{ wc }}
{% endfor %}
```

By doing `{{ response.wc }}` Django will try to do three things: a lookup for `response["wc"]`, a call to `response.wc()` or attribute getting `response.wc` and a list lookup `response[wc]` where `wc` is an index. Depending on your code behind, it could change the `response` object.

Comment: This code prints the keys in response. I want the values.

Comment: As [the docs clearly show](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for), if you want the value you use `{% for k, v in response.items %}{{ v }}{% endfor %}`. This is exactly the same as cycling through a dictionary in plain python.

Comment: And this was the solution I actually went with. Or rather, it was the solution I tried first, but did not work since response is a DefaultDict, which cannot be iterated over. (found out this is a known bug in Django) Changing to a normal dict, and using response.items, worked as expected.

It still does not change that it is weird behavior for python to throw a fit because I am reading a value while iterating.

Comment: Why you don't share info? You never said nothing about DefaultDict, and now it's the source of your error. I bet it you share enough code, we will probably find the actual problem and it will be not Python or Django being weird or buggy.

BTW, trying to get a missing key from a DefaultDict *actually very much changes the contents* of the dictionary. It is, in fact, the key feature of a DefaultDict. So both Django or Python has all the right to complain about it.

Answer (score 0):

[**Important reference 1**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6285769/13861187)

```
{% for wc in response %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ response.wc }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Seems incorrect.

**Use as below.**

```
{% for wc in response %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ wc }}</td>
        <td>{{ wc.any_key_attribute_name }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

`wc` is the current value of for loop. You should use that.
You can access attributes of this `wc` object like `wc.attribute_name`.

---

**For dictionaries**

Example dictionary.

```
choices = {'key1':'val1', 'key2':'val2'}
```

Access dictionary as below.

```
<ul>
{% for key, value in choices.items %} 
  <li>{{key}} - {{value}}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

[Reference 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6285769/13861187)

Comment: This code prints the keys in response. I want the values.

Comment: Ok. That's because we guessed the normal structure of response. Since you haven't posted it. If you post the response / response structure / example response, we can give 100% valid answer.

Comment: Did you try `wc.attribute_name ` ?

Comment: respond.wc is a list, so I don't know what attributes I could call.

Comment: "I am trying to iterate over a dictionary containing lists." Don't know why you are trying to guess the structure, when I have already stated it?

Comment: No. You haven't provided example dictionary. That's why answering is hard. Show us some example dictionary.

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/a/1724201/13861187 .

Comment: `Since you haven't posted ` that's why we guess.

Comment: He's not even looping a dictionary, but a defaultdict. The problem is he's probably trying to get a missing key, with causes the defaultdict to insert a new key (as intended), and thus changing its size.